# Combine and add 2 arrays typescript, lodash, underscore

Tags: typescript, lodash

I have an array of objects that looks like this:

```
[  
  {date: '2016-09-10', 'Post': 5, 'Pickup': 2},  
  {date: '2016-09-11', 'Post': 8, 'Pickup': 2},  
  {date: '2016-09-12', 'Post': 0, 'Pickup': 2},  
  {date: '2016-09-12', 'Post': 3, 'Pickup': 0},  
  {date: '2016-09-13', 'Post': 1, 'Pickup': 2},  
  {date: '2016-09-13', 'Post': 1, 'Pickup': 0},  
]
```

I need to combine the objects by date and add post+post and pickup+pickup to look like this:

```
[  
  {date: '2016-09-10', 'Post': 5, 'Pickup': 2},  
  {date: '2016-09-11', 'Post': 8, 'Pickup': 2},  
  {date: '2016-09-12', 'Post': 3, 'Pickup': 2},  
  {date: '2016-09-13', 'Post': 2, 'Pickup': 2},  
]
```

I would prefer lodash and/or underscore.
Thanks.

I started with 2 arrays like this:

```
pickup = [  
      {date: '2016-09-11', 'Post': 8, 'Pickup': 2},  
      {date: '2016-09-12', 'Post': 3, 'Pickup': 0},  
      {date: '2016-09-13', 'Post': 1, 'Pickup': 0},  
    ]  

post = [  
      {date: '2016-09-10', 'Post': 5, 'Pickup': 2},  
      {date: '2016-09-12', 'Post': 0, 'Pickup': 2},  
      {date: '2016-09-13', 'Post': 1, 'Pickup': 2},  
    ]
```

I used `data = _.unionBy( post, pickup, 'date' );`
and `_.uniqBy( data, 'date' );`

Comment: @talkdirty see my new edits above. I am new to lodash and underscore.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could use [**reduce**](https://lodash.com/docs/4.15.0#reduce) and create a new object in the resulting array for new dates, or just add to the `Posts` and `Pickups` if there already is one:

```
var result = _.reduce(array, function (memo, el) {
  var d = _.find(memo, function(e) { return e.date === el.date });
  if (d) {
    d.Post += el.Post;
    d.Pickup += el.Pickup;
  } else {
    memo.push(_.clone(el));
  }
  return memo;
}, []);
```

```js
var array = [  
  {date: '2016-09-10', 'Post': 5, 'Pickup': 2},  
  {date: '2016-09-11', 'Post': 8, 'Pickup': 2},  
  {date: '2016-09-12', 'Post': 0, 'Pickup': 2},  
  {date: '2016-09-12', 'Post': 3, 'Pickup': 0},  
  {date: '2016-09-13', 'Post': 1, 'Pickup': 2},  
  {date: '2016-09-13', 'Post': 1, 'Pickup': 0} 
];

var result = _.reduce(array, function (memo, el) {
  var d = _.find(memo, function(e) { return e.date === el.date });
  if (d) {
    d.Post += el.Post;
    d.Pickup += el.Pickup;
  } else {
    memo.push(_.clone(el));
  }
  return memo;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.15.0/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This will trash/overwrite the original objects in the array, if that's an issue.

Comment: Or `_.findWhere(memo, {date: el.date})` if you are so inclined.

Answer (score -1):

```
var res = _.chain(array)
    .groupBy('date')
    .mapValues(function(dateArray) {
        return {
            'Post': _.chain(dateArray).map('Post').sum().value(),
            'Pickup': _.chain(dateArray).map('Pickup').sum().value(),
            'date': _.first(dateArray).date
        }
    })
    .values()
    .value();
```